# Call function when another is called

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function, for example, boot:

```
function boot(){
    return("Arbitrary value");
}
```

Like you can listen for the onload, onclick, onkeydown, etc., is there any easy way (Without modifying the boot function) to do a sort of onboot?

[EDIT]

Seeing confusion, I will explain more.

Imagine a script that I have no control over is imported. The boot function is randomly called, and when the boot function is called, the script I have no control over wants to do something. Whoever wrote the script would like to do something like this: onboot = function(){consoe.log("whatever")}

Is this something that is possible?

Thanks,
-Dylan

Comment: just to make sure I get it.
function bar() {
// stuff
}

function foo() {
// other stuff
}

you want foo to be called once bar is called?

Comment: Yes, but without calling foo inside bar

Comment: After you call `boot` just call the other functions?

Comment: how do you call boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). My solution creates a custom event, which will be triggered by the calling function.

Let's say we have functions `base` and `called`, `base` calling `called` once complete:

```
var onboot = new Event('onboot');

document.addEventListener('onboot' called);

function base () { 
  // I do stuff 
  console.log("base");
  document.dispatchEvent(onboot);
}

function called () {
  // do stuff here 
  console.log("called");
}
```

So if you call `base` now, you'll get this result:

[image]

Comment: but, why don't you just call `called` inside `base` ?

Comment: Did you read my question? I have no control over called. I have no clue what called will be named, how many functions called could represent, nothing. I just need to dispatch the boot even when boot is called :D

Comment: but, when I do `addEventListener`, I put the name of the function to be called. So it requires the name of the function to be called in order to work.

Comment: The other person does that. I just created a function called onboot(functionName) that adds it to the event listener for them, and I just eval the function when the boot function is called. Simple! I am getting a vm error tho, might just be my programming... "Unexpected token )"

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to what you want, but not without modifying boot. You can change the boot function so that you can register event handlers that are called whenever boot is called with something like this:

```
var callbacks = [];
function boot() {
    callbacks.forEach(function(f) { f(); });
    return "Arbitrary value";
}
function registerBootCallback(f) {
    callbacks.push(f);
}
```

Note that the boot function doesn't need to explicitly call the handlers.

If you can't modify the boot function itself, but you control everywhere it is called, create a new function that calls boot and all the callbacks, and call that instead of boot directly. If you can't change boot and don't control everywhere it is called, (and some kind of callback mechanism doesn't already exist) then you are out of luck.

There are also probably libraries that make this a little easier, and allow you to do things like event propagation.

Comment: Good answer but I would modify it to just say "No, not without modifying boot"

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the `boot` function in your code without changing it in the script.

```
var real_boot = boot
boot = function () {
    // insert your code
    real_boot()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is globally accessible. You can overwrite the function with your own function and then call old function inside your own function.

Eg

other-lib.js

```
function boot(){
    //Do something internally that you dont have control over
}
```

your-file.js

```
var oldBoot = boot;
function boot(){
   oldBoot.call(this, arguments);
   //Do your stuff here
}
```